# Actual and expected values in NUnit test for format decimal extension not the same

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I wrote the following extension method:

```
public static class DecimalExtensions
{
   public static string FormatCurrency(this decimal instance)
   {
      return string.Format("{0:c}", instance);
   }
}
```

The NUnit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DecimalExtensionsTests
{
   [Test]
   public void Format_should_return_formatted_decimal_string()
   {
      // Arrange
      decimal amount = 1000;

      // Act
      string actual = amount.FormatCurrency();

      // Assert
      Assert.AreEqual("R 1 000,00", actual);
   }
}
```

My test is failing and I am not sure why.  The error that I get is the following:

```
String lengths are both 10. Strings differ at index 3.
  Expected: "R 1 000,00"
  But was:  "R 1 000,00"
  --------------^
```

Comment: Check the actual character values at index 3, compare int to int. Not all spaces are created equal.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Have you got some code?

Comment: Consider `string foo = "12345"; string bar = "123 5"; int x = (int)foo[3]; int y = (int)bar[3];`. This pulls the character at index 3 in each string, casts to `int`. Then you can simply look at the integer values and see what they are. In your problem, where you are expecting a space of one value, the currency format may be returning what looks like a space but is actually a different character value. You can then evaluate and adjust your expectation.

Comment: The idea is that you might be expecting a space from the ASCII table (character value 32). ASCII ranges from 0-127. But `char` is a 16 bit value that can be more than just ASCII. In non-ASCII, there could be a space that is anything up to 65535, if expressed as an integer, and the currency format could be returning something beyond ASCII's range. At any rate, it appears to be returning a space that is *not* the precise space you expect.

Comment: I would have scratched my head quite a bit if I had encountered that problem, that's pretty devious.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem indeed comes from different space representation in numeric format. Space you're having troubles with is defined in [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) class' [`CurrencyGroupSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupseparator.aspx) property. If you check character codes of both standard ASCII space and currency group separator space with the following snippet

```
Console.WriteLine("Space code: {0}", (Int32)' ');
var separator = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat
    .CurrencyGroupSeparator;
Console.WriteLine("Currency separator code: {0}", (Int32)separator[0]);
```

... you'll find that it prints `32` and `160` respectively. This is why your string comparison fails.

For the purpose of unit testing, you can set the separator to actual ASCII space, like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = " ";
```

However, I would **advise against it**. You need to consider what happens when developer with other culture settings will run your unit test. Most likely it will fail, as resulting strings might differ. To make your method more usable (**and unit tests more isolated**), simply add overload that accepts culture info:

```
public static string FormatCurrency(this decimal instance)
{
   return instance.FormatCurrency(Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo);
}

public static string FormatCurrency(this decimal instance, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return string.Format(culture, "{0:c}", instance);
}
```

In your unit test, you write test against second method, with some well-known and easy to verify culture settings (might even fix the space to make it easier):

```
[Test]
public void FormatCurrency_should_return_formatted_decimal_string()
{
    decimal amount = 1000;
    var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us");
    // replacing space (160) with space (32)
    culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = " ";

    // Act
    string actual = amount.FormatCurrency(culture);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("$1 000.00", actual);
}
```

And in your real application you simply use culture-less overload and let the culture be the one from user's current settings.